# Restricting value types in a C# Dictionary:

Tags: c#, dictionary, types

What I want is a `Dictionary<string, T>` where `T` is restricted to one of a few types.

If C# had Typescript union types it would look something like `Dictionary<string, bool | string | int | List<string> | List<int>>`

What I did is write a wrapper class around Dictionary which has a bunch of overloads of `Add()` for individual supported types, and methods like `GetBool()` and `GetString()` for retrieval. See http://pastebin.com/av7nE5az

This works, but it's verbose and ugly and tedious to extend and I think there must be a better way. Anybody got one?

Edit: Some questions about why I want this. Basically I want `Dictionary<string, object>`, with an instance perhaps containing values of multiple types, but I expect to use it in a constrained way (in a game) so the list of possible value types is limited. I could get by with just using `Dictionary<string, object>` and casting every retrieval, but I have the idea that it will be nicer if I can build more type awareness into the data structure itself.

Comment: You can only restrict T to a single base type, and since the only common base type between `int` and `List<int>` is `object` there's no way to restrict `T` any further.

Comment: If C# allowed `Dictionary<string, bool | string | int | List<string> | List<int>>`, you'd lose type safety when iterating over the collection since the type of the value would not be known at compile time. I don't know what you are trying to achieve but it sounds like a wrapper class might be the way to go.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I think the OP want to allow `Dictionary<string, int>` and `Dictionary<string, bool>` but not `Dictionary<string, Form>` - not to allow multiple value types in one dictionary.

Comment: I would like a dict object to be able to contain both bools and ints as values for different keys, but to reject attempts to add (say) an Exception as a value.

Comment: If you declare a dictionary such that it can contain ints and bools but "reject" attempts to add an exception, that would mean you would have to say `Dictionary<..., object>`, whereas if you declared it as `Dictionary<..., int>`, it could never hold anything but ints as values, no exceptions, no bools. Can you clarify exactly what you're looking for and why?

Comment: The only way to restrict the possible types for a generic parameter is to use the `where` constraint clause when declaring the type. Unfortunately there is nothing in common between the types you want possible that aren't also in common with lots of other types. Restricting to a set of classes you have declared is rather easy as you can add an interface and restrict the generic parameter to be a type that implements this interface but for the types provided by .NET you're out of luck.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to have simpler code and compile-time type checks, you can use this method, although it may slightly impact performance.

1. Define your dictionary as `Dictionary<string, MyEntry>`
2. Write a new class `MyEntry` that is capable of storing all of the data types of interest.
3. Write [implicit conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) between `MyEntry` and the data types of interest. It might look something like this example, which can handle `bool` and `int` (you can extend this for other data types as needed):

   ```
   class MyEntry
   {
       private Type _type = typeof(object);
       private bool _boolValue = false;
       private int _intValue = 0;

       public MyEntry(bool b)
       {
           _type = typeof(bool);
           _boolValue = b;
       }

       public MyEntry(int i)
       {
           _type = typeof(int);
           _intValue = i;
       }

       public static implicit operator bool(MyEntry e)
       {
           if (e._type != typeof(bool)) throw new InvalidCastException();
           return e._boolValue;
       }
       public static implicit operator MyEntry(bool b)
       {
           return new MyEntry(b);
       }
       public static implicit operator int(MyEntry e)
       {
           if (e._type != typeof(int)) throw new InvalidCastException();
           return e._intValue;
       }
       public static implicit operator MyEntry(int i)
       {
           return new MyEntry(i);
       }
   }
   ```
4. You can then write concise code to read and write from this dictionary without explicit casts.  You can control which types are allowed by restricting the implicit casts that are implemented for `MyEntry`.

   ```
   var d = new Dictionary<string, MyEntry>();
   d.Add("IntegerOne", 1);
   d.Add("BooleanTrue", true);
   d.Add("FloatThree", 3.0f);  //Will not compile

   bool b = d["BooleanTrue"];
   int i = d["IntegerOne"];
   float f = d["FloatThree"]; //Will not compile

   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("BooleanTrue = '{0}'", b));
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("IntegerOne = '{0}'", i));
   ```

Comment: This is interesting and might work (performance hit would be fine). I'll try it out, thanks.